# I get this error TypeError: string indices must be integers in my Python code

Tags: python, typeerror, attributeerror

So I am getting data from an API that looks like this

```
{
 "id": "f25d3e90",
 "name": "project"
}
```

and here is the portion of my code

```
data = stratComLibrary.dataGet("v1/package/get-all-by-name?name="+project_num+"&substrMatch=true")
projectId = ""
modelId = ""
assemblyCadIds = []
for i in data:
    if i.get("number") == ticket_num:
        projectId = (i['projectId'])
        modelId = (i['modelId'])
        assemblyCadIds = (i.get('assemblyCadIds', []))

data2 = stratComLibrary.dataGet("v1/project/"+projectId+"?include=name%2C%20id")
projectName = ""
for i in data2:
    projectName = (i['name'])
```

the first request works for the data variable but then I get this error on the second request

```
File "path", line 32, in main
projectName = (i['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

whenever I do print(i) it gives me a string "id".. not too sure what is going on here but it's

Comment: What is the type of `data2`?

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on dictionaries.  You don't seem to understand what `for i in data2` does.  `i` iterates through the dict keys, each of which is a string.  You try to index that string with another string, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"for i in data2"
is iterating over the data2 dict keys. 
So i = "id" and "id" is not an object.

What you want is:
projectName = data2['name']